# Error Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, html, html5

Intento hacer una galería de imágenes utilizando funciones obtenerImagen y subirImagen, pero me tira el error de Undefined Index, ahora paso el código:

```
 <?php
include_once "funciones.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>TP Galeria</title>
        
        <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="js/funciones.js"></script>
    
    </head>
<body>

<form name="add_contacto" id="id_add_contacto" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="procesar.php">
<div id="contenedor_form" class="contenedor_form">
    <h2 class="titulos"> Galeria de Imagenes v1.0</h2>
    <h1 class="titulos"> Subir Imagen</h1>
        <input  name="fotos" type="file" placeholder="Seleccionar Imagen" class="campos_file"/>
        <input  name="btn_enviar" type="submit" value="Agregar Imagen a Galeria" class="campos_btn"/>
</div>
</form>
<br />
<?php

$lista_imagenes = obtenerImagenes("imagenes");


if( $lista_imagenes){
    echo '<div class="imagen_contenedor">';

    foreach($lista_imagenes as $c){
        echo '
        <div class="imagen_item">
            <a href="imagenes/'.$c.'" target="_blank"><img class="img_tabla" src="imagenes/'.$c.'"></a>
        </div>';    
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
?>
<br /><br /><br />
</body>    
</html>
```

Estas son las funciones (como dice los comentarios, en la función obtenerImagen debo guardar las imagenes en un arreglo y mostrarlo, y en caso de tener un error devolver False:

```
<?php
  function subirImagen($file){
// la funcion debe subir una imagen a la carpeta "imagenes" y devolver el nombre de la imagen o false si hay algun error
if(validar($_FILES)){
    $ruta = 'imagenes/';
    $nombreArchivo = $_FILES['fotos']['name'];

    $ruta = $ruta . basename($nombreArchivo);
    

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fotos']['tmp_name'], $ruta)){
        return $nombreArchivo;
    }
}else{
    return false;
}
}

function validar($file){    


$tipoArchivo = $_FILES['fotos']['type'];
$tamañoArchivo = $_FILES['fotos']['size'];

if (!((strpos($tipoArchivo, "png") || strpos($tipoArchivo, "jpeg")))){
    return false;
}

if ($tamañoArchivo > 600000){
    return false;
}

return true;

}

function obtenerImagenes($carpeta){
    // la funcion debe leer el contenido le la carpeta donde se guardan la imagenes, ese valor viene dado por la variable $carpeta
    // guardar el nombre de las imagenes en una arreglo y devolver este arreglo, en caso de error debe devolver false
    $dir = 'imagenes';
    $carpeta = dir($dir);
    $arr = array();
    while (($img = $carpeta->read()) !== false) {
        if ((strpos($img,'gif')) !== false || (strpos($img,'jpg')) !== false || (strpos($img,'png')) !== false){ 
            $arr = $img;
        }
    }

    if(validar($_FILES)){
        var_dump($_FILES);
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
}
?>
```

Y el error que me tira es el siguiente:

> Notice: Undefined index: fotos in C:\xampp\htdocs\tp-recuperatorio-final-esqueleto\funciones.php on line 22
>
> Notice: Undefined index: fotos in C:\xampp\htdocs\tp-recuperatorio-final-esqueleto\funciones.php on line 23

He intentado colocar los $_FILES en variables y luego llamarlas, cambiado el name del input por uno distinto y nada. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Hola el error te dice que la variable $_FILES['fotos']['type']; su index fotos no existe, puedes corroborar si trae algo o si el formulario fue enviado, puedes hacer print_r($_FILES) a ver que te arroja. y comentas.